# Javascript cannot get value for operation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following issue. Since there're many, many business rules I've decided to enter those functions as js to update automatically.

In my view i have:
this is inside a table

```
(<%= javascript_include_tag 'people'%>)

      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Money</th>
      <th>Money Comment</th>
    </tr>
    <% @counter = 0 %>
    <% @people.each do |p| %>
    <% @counter += 1 %>
     <tr>
     <%= form_for(:p) do |f| %>
     <th><%= f.label(p.name) %></th>
     <th><label for="<%= "money_" + @counter.to_s %>"> <%= f.select(:money, 1..10,   :selected => p.money)%></label></th>
     <th><label for="<%= "comment_" + @counter.to_s %>"> <%= f.label(p.money_comment, :disabled => 'disabled')%></label></th>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

and in the javascript the function looks like this:

```
function change_people() {
  money1 = $('money_1').getValue();
  if (money1 == 10) {
    $('comment_2').setValue("I know what you're doing you mofo");
  } 
  else {
    $('comment_2').setValue("");
  }
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  change_people();
  $('money_1').observe('change', change_people);
});
```

but for some reason it keeps telling me it doesn't know what I mean by "money_1". I check the html source and is compiling the view, am I referencing the element wrongly in js?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please use the code markup ({}) in the editor for the code you've included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you need a selector:

```
<th id="<%= "money_" + @counter.to_s %>">
 <label for="<%= "money_" + @counter.to_s %>"> 
  <%= f.select(:money, 1..10,   :selected => p.money)%>
 </label>
</th>
```

Now you've given Prototype the ability to search and find the correct element (the select with the value you're looking for), which you pass to the $() function to call getValue():

```
function change_people() {
    // Note the "#" on #money_1, which is an ID selector
    // the space " " between is a descendant element selector
    money1 = $($$('#money_1 select')).getValue();
    if (money1 == 10) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

If you're looking to iterate over all of the money select values in the table, you would instead want to use a class; you are only allowed to have one element per ID, but a class by rule is grouped by attribute. The difference would be:

```
<th class="money_select">
 <label for="<%= "money_" + @counter.to_s %>"> 
  <%= f.select(:money, 1..10,   :selected => p.money)%>
 </label>
</th>
```

And then in your javascript:

```
function change_people() {
    // Note the "." on .money_1, which is a class selector
    // the space " " between is a descendant element selector
    $$('.money_select select').each(function(element){
        if ($(element).getValue() == 10) {
            // do stuff
        } else {
            // do other stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jared, just tried adding this to the js, but it gave me the same error. now it just changed the name of what it tells me is wrong.   money1 = $('#money_1').getValue(); Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getValue' of null

Comment: @Lievcin: Also, if you could post the source html the browser is seeing instead of the ruby code, that would help.

Comment: Well, when i assign the id, it does this for one of the selects, the first one, but the rails is creating another one, from the f.select code and that one's id is "p_money", but the problem is that is the same "p_money" for every row!                  <th><select for="money_1"> <select id="p_money" name="p[money]"><option value="1">1</option>

Comment: I believe you could do that with <%= f.select(:money, 1..10, :id => "money_" + @counter.to_s, :selected => p.money)%>.

Comment: That's exactly what i was trying, but it doesn't affect the source code at all, it still show me the same select id. Argg!

Comment: Add it to the TH like this: <th id="<%= "money_" + @counter.to_s %>"><label for="<%= "money_" + @counter.to_s %>"> <%= f.select(:money, 1..10, :selected => p.money)%></label></th> and then select using that: $('#money_1 select').getValue()

Comment: Ok, I've set the property as you suggested on th! It at least seems to be doing that fine now. It didn't at first, but then I changed the js back to   money1 = $('money_1').valueOf();
and now it worked. But is throwing me an error on the next item, which is to set the text on the other lable to a text. It says Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'setValue'

Comment: Are you using jQuery or another library?

Comment: Erm... to be honest i have no clue. I haven't added anything to what comes by default with the app.

Comment: Without knowing what library is being used (including a proprietary version created by the software vendor), it will be difficult to troubleshoot what the issue is. What software package is it? (Note: the $() function is not a basic part of Javascript.)

Comment: I havent changed anything since creating the app, the only places where I see the getValue and setValue functions being defined is in the prototype.js file

Comment: Ah ha, this makes a lot of sense. Prototype is one of the major (and in fact Ruby-specific) javascript libraries. Since it uses the $() function, like MooTools and jQuery and many others, what you pass as the first argument to that function is important. Prototype, for instance, automatically assumes that text refers to an ID, whereas jQuery would require $('#id') for it work the same.

See: http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/extensions 

You really need to review that link to see what Prototype is looking for. jQuery is quite a bit different (it's more like CSS selectors).

Comment: Do you think it would be easier to accomplish using jQuery functions instead of Prototype?

Comment: I just need to obviosly make it replicable because there will be many functions to manage the rules in place. Thanks for your help Jared!

Comment: No, I don't think you need to switch. Prototype is a bit different from jQuery, however, in how it works. One way is that $() is an alias of document.getElementById(), so any text passed to it will only find a matching element with that id. jQuery uses selectors, so it's a bit more complex with what it allows you to do from $(). That said, the $$() function operations in a similar way to jQuery's $(), so use that instead. http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar

Comment: So, $($$('#money_1 select')).getValue() looks like what you want to get the th#money_1 select value. http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/element/getValue (Just a note as well - the $() in Prototype accepts both an id or an element reference, hence passing the $$() into the $() function to select the correct element, then doing the getValue() call on the result from $().)